# `gdb` gives different results for `ret` and natural return

Tags: c, arrays, memory, gdb, segmentation-fault

I have the following function:

```
edge** graph_out_edges(graph* g, int src) {
    int i;
    int num_edges = 0;
    edge** es = (edge**) malloc(sizeof(edge*) * g->num_edges);

    for (i = 0; i < g->num_edges; i++) {
        if (src == g->edges[i]->src) {
            es[num_edges++] = g->edges[i];
        }
    }

    es[num_edges] = NULL;
    return es;
}
```

I add a breakpoint to the function using `b graph_out_edges`, run the program using `r`, and then continue (`c`) twice (I get a segfault if I continue again). I then `n` through the function until it moves to the command just after the call to the function

```
edge** new = graph_out_edges(g, min->dest);
```

`p new[0]` and `p new[1]` give valid edges (the members are populated), and `p new[2]` gives `0x0`, as expected. I then type `r` to restart the program, again continuing twice, but this time I then type `ret` (confirming I want to return), type `n` to execute the assignment, but now when I type `p new[0]` I get

```
Cannot access memory at address 0x2
```

(Just for clarity, `p new` now says `$10 = (edge**) 0x2`)

Any suggestions on why there is this discrepancy between the return value when "`n`exting" through the function manually and forcing a return?

Comment: you do not check the value of `es` after the malloc. Make sure that malloc does not return NULL.

Comment: [Please don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169). Also, if all of the incoming edges match, the loop will end with `num_edges == g->num_edges` and the final sentinel-write of `NULL` will overflow the buffer. Danger!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the function, if you guarantee the value of es is right, then after the call, the value of new should be right.

Perhaps, I suppose that,

```
First, check the es;
Then, compare the return value of new with es.
```

Comment: This highlighted an incorrect assumption I had, that `ret` in `gdb` executed the function until natural return, but in fact it discards the stack frame, so I'm going to mark this as correct.

Comment: As an additional note, `finish` in `gdb` is the command I should have been using, which continues execution until natural return.